# Find all occurences of exact string in range and list it

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api, google-sheets-formula

I want to create list of all occurences of "x" string in range. This is my sheet:

[image]

And I want to search all occurences and list them and give proper names:
For example for G2, I want "Beret Grey" string as result. I think that I need to use array formula or something like that.

Comment: If you are using [google-sheets] (per your comment below) then why on earth would you tag this question [excel] and [excel-formula] with no mention of the actual platform you are working on? Don't throw crap at a wall to see what sticks. Down-voted with slight regard.

Comment: But I thought that excel and google sheets are really, really similar, but now I see that I was wrong propably...

Answer (score 1):

Let me first preface this that vba would be much more robust, but this formula will get you there.  It may be slow as it is an array type formula and is doing a lot of calculations.  These calculations only expound exponentially as the number of cells with them in it increases:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(A:A,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($B$2:$G$7)/($B$2:$G$7="x"),ROW(1:1))) & " " & INDEX($1:$1,AGGREGATE(15,6,COLUMN(INDEX(A:G,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($B$2:$G$7)/($B$2:$G$7="x"),ROW(1:1)),0))/(INDEX(A:G,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($B$2:$G$7)/($B$2:$G$7="x"),ROW(1:1)),0)="x"),ROW(1:1)-COUNTIF($B$1:INDEX(G:G,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($B$2:$G$7)/($B$2:$G$7="x"),ROW(1:1)) -1),"x"))),"")
```

[image]

You will need to expand the range to what you need.  Change all the `$B$2:$G$7` to `$B$2:$N$29`.  Do not use full column references outside those that I have used.  It will kill Excel.

Also note what is and what is not relative references, they need to remain the same or you will get errors as the formula is dragged/copied down.

---

As simple UDF to do what you want:

```
Function findMatch(rng As Range, crit As String, inst As Long) As String
Dim rngArr() As Variant
rngArr = rng.Value
Dim i&, j&, k&
k = 0
If k > Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rng, crit) Then
    findMatch = ""
    Exit Function
End If

For i = LBound(rngArr, 1) + 1 To UBound(rngArr, 1)
    For j = LBound(rngArr, 2) + 1 To UBound(rngArr, 2)
        If rngArr(i, j) = crit Then
            k = k + 1
            If k = inst Then
                findMatch = rngArr(i, 1) & " " & rngArr(1, j)
                Exit Function
            End If
        End If
    Next j
Next i
```

then you would call it like this:

```
=findMatch($A$1:$G$7,"x",ROW(1:1))
```

And drag/copy down.

[image]

Comment: Hello, could you tell me is there any other way to ignore error values instead of using AGGREGATE formula like you did? Because I'm doing everything from these on google sheets and AGGREGATE formula doesn't exist there :/ Or maybe you know how to convert your VBA to GAS (Google Appscript)?

Comment: That is not what you asked.  This has answered what you asked. if you want a new/different answer, ask a new/different question. @Jackenmen

Comment: Ok, just wanted to know, if you know how to do this :)